# Equivalent to remote_function using jquery and jquery-rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building an app in Rails 3.0.3 and Ruby 1.9.2. I have installed the jquery-rails gem and use jquery instead of prototype. I have a .js.erb will update the contents of the div tag but I need to call a function in the controller to get updated information for the div tag. Can someone provide an example or point me to one? I have tried the railscasts unobtrusive javascript tutorial but I can not get is to work for my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [How to make Ajax calls with Rails 3 using remote_function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332474/how-to-make-ajax-calls-with-rails-3-using-remote-function/) and my comment there. The answer of Ibz, adding :remote, only makes sense for form elements and even then is only a part of the story.

Comment: Please try `link_to "Name", url_path, :remote => true`

Comment: My mistake: form elements *and some additional ones*. However, if you're not dealing with one of the select few that support :remote, you need to resort to adding a handler via jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 all the `remote_methods` helpers have been removed. To make them work with AJAX, simply pass the `:remote => true` option to the original non-remote method.

Reference: [Unobtrusive JavaScript in Rails 3](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/)