# How to calculate a default value for a form text field in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form for `payments` like this:

```
<%= f.label :invoice_id %>
<%= f.select(:invoice_id, current_user.outstanding_invoices_collection) %>

<%= f.label :amount %>
<%= f.text_field :amount %>
```

I wonder if there's a way to populate the value of the `amount` text field somehow, e.g. with the open balance of the associated `invoice`?

In my `Invoice` model have this function:

```
def balance
  payments.map(&:amount).sum - total
end
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Your question is about calculating the default value, and not setting the default value, right? You can set a default value with `<%= f.text_field :amount, :value => "my default value" %>`

Comment: Hm yes, but wouldn't it be better to calculate it in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming you want to populate the text box based on the selection of a invoice from dropdown. In that case

The idea is

- You need to make a ajax call onchange of the invoice dropdown.
- That ajax response should update the value of the text box.

And with rails-3 i think its recommended to do this in unrobustive way. [Here is a link you can follow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4958088/1160106). Start playing with it meanwhile I will try to make something functional. Hope to get a good result again.

Are you looking for how to populate the value only?

**Update:**

Here is the ajax part

```
#Application.js or any sutable js file
$(function($) {
    $("#your_drop_down_id").change(function() {
        #Your the url to your controller action here
        $.ajax({url: '/get_amount',
        data: 'invoice_id=' + this.value,
        dataType: 'script'})
    });
});
```

---

```
#in get_amount Action
invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id]) #Other appropriate logic to get the invoice
@amount = invoice.balance
```

---

```
#get_amount.js.erb
$('#your_text_box_id').val('<%= @amount %>');
```

---

```
#routes.rb
#This part is written following the gist: https://gist.github.com/3889180 by @TinTin
resources :payments do  
   collection do
       get 'get_amount'
   end
end
```

Let me know if any part is confusing to you.

Comment: Yes, actually I was looking for ways to populate the value. But it would be nice if that value changed accordingly if the associated `invoice_id` gets changed in the select box. Thanks for your link. I am studying it right now. Not sure if I can get it to work, though. I am a jQuery n00b still...

Comment: i could make it... im updating my post and it will be done shortly :)

Comment: Ive updated with the example, the line in js.erb will actually update the value of text box. ive shown only the way to introduce ajax in your case. But the `controller actions`, `url`, `model method` etc need to be changed according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I could not get this to work though. Can you have a look at [my gist](https://gist.github.com/3889180) and tell me what I am doing wrong? Maybe I need a `:remote => true` on one of the form elements?

Comment: Did you fix your route for `get_amount` method? Ive added a route in my answer. You may follow that way. You dont need `:remote=>true` because `$.ajax` is actually making the ajax call.

Comment: I couldnt find any problem in your gist. In case you are already using correct route path, can you add the response coming for this ajax request? You can get this by `firebug(of firefox)` or `Inspect>Network tool(of Google Chrome)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18014/discussion-between-samiron-and-tintin81)

Comment: Hello, hope you slept well. I couldn't get it to work unfortunately. I updated [the gist](https://gist.github.com/3889180) with some more controller code. Any more ideas?

Comment: Yes, it's fixed. Thank you very much! Is there anything I can do for you in return?

Comment: Oh im glad its fixed.. but i am really interested to know how did you fixed it finally?

Comment: In fact I had placed the `get_amount` resource in the wrong place. I simply put it at the top of my `routes.rb` file and everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller you can assign any value to any field, and it will be displayed in the view.

```
def new
  @payment = new Payment()
  @payment.amount = 100
end
```

If you want some dynamic value, e.g: based on a combobox selection, then do it in javascript or with AJAX.

Comment: OK, I am on the right track then. In my controller I have    `@payment.amount = @payment.invoice.balance.abs if @payment.invoice.present?`. It just felt a little clumsy to me...

Comment: During creation probably you have no `@payment.invoice`, or have you? If you have, it can be shortened a bit.

Comment: There might be a `@payment.invoice` before creation sometimes. But anyway, I get the idea. Thanks for your help.