# rails 3 remote_function Prototype conversion to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, prototype

How can I accomplish this in rails 3.1?

```
<input type="radio" name='radiotype' value='ord' checked="checked"
                    onclick="<%= remote_function(:controller=>'controllername', :update => 'wrapper', :action => :radiotype, :with => 'Form.Element.serialize(this)' ) %>"
                />
```

I have looked around and i know the remote_function has gone, how could i do thiw with jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make Ajax calls with Rails 3 using remote\_function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332474/how-to-make-ajax-calls-with-rails-3-using-remote-function)