# Unknown keyword ensure issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails 4 app, where I have a line like:

```
<%= f.select :type_of, %w[Bookshelf Birdhouse Book Cabinet], {},
                onChange: "alert("<%= render 'stores/product_form/bookshelf', f:f %>")" %>
<div id='newContent'>
  <%= render 'stores/product_form/bookshelf', f:f %>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is onChange of the select, render a partial in a specified div #newContent and replace the current contents of the div like with jQuery's html() function.

Is this possible? Right now, with my current code I get the error:

```
html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'
```

---

**EDIT**

Here's my new select/dropdown code:

```
<%= f.select :type_of, %w[Bookshelf Birdhouse Book Cabinet], {}, class: "",
                onChange: 'alert(" #{ raw(render "stores/product_form/bookshelf", f:f)} ")' %>
```

I've tried it with raw and without and both ways still don't render out as ruby code, they just get rendered as html

Comment: Which html.erb is causing the issue? Also, you can have `onChange: "alert("<%= render 'stores/product_form/bookshelf', f:f %>")"` as: `onChange: 'alert("#{ render "stores/product_form/bookshelf", f:f}")'` Try this?

Comment: As @Surya suggests, you can't use a tag `<%= %>` inside another one. Use the basic string interpolation notation in these case: `onChange: "alert('#{ render 'stores/product_form/bookshelf', f: f }')" `

Comment: Also, take a note of `quotes - single and double` in Surya's suggestion that might be causing the syntax error in your current code.

Comment: Ok, I've tried interpolating the strings, but now its not rendering as rails code anymore? `<select name="store[type_of]" onchange="alert(&quot; #{ render &quot;stores/product_form/bookshelf&quot;, f:f} &quot;)">`

Comment: That was the rendered html of the new.html.erb file

Comment: String interpolation is done within double quotes `"#{...}"`, I suppose you used single quotes instead. Did you try the exact same code as suggested by Surya `onChange: 'alert("#{ render "stores/product_form/bookshelf", f:f}")'`

Comment: @kirtiThorat, I just updated my question with the changes I made

Comment: @infinity What are you trying to do, buddy? It'll of course throw HTML code rendered from 'stores/product_form/bookshelf' partial into `alert` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the render too soon. You don't want the contents of the partial rendered into the onChange handler. What you want is for the onChange handler to *trigger* the rendering of the partial.

You want something like this:

```
User Selects Option in Dropdown
            |
            v
onChange Handler Runs
            |
            v
Handler triggers AJAX request
            |
            v
Server returns javascript partial
            |
            v
Handler processes AJAX response
            |
            v
AJAX response renders HTML onto page
```

Check out [How to make Ajax calls with Rails 3 using remote_function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332474/how-to-make-ajax-calls-with-rails-3-using-remote-function) for some actual code examples.